# Accented and unaccented letters are equal in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, collation

I have a table in a MariaDB  database, which contains words of any language. The problem is that, for example, `'a' == 'á'` is considered `true`.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select 'a' = 'á';
+------------+
| 'a' = 'á'  |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

The words' column is marked `UNIQUE` in the table, which is good to prevent duplicates, but it treats, for example, 'arat' and 'árát' the same, so the insertion of 'arat' fails if 'árát' is already present, which is not the expected behaviour, both words should be allowed to present in the table parallelly.

I'm using MariaDB 10.7.3-1 on ArchLinux.
How to set MariaDB to differentiate these words?

Answer (score 1):

Use COLLATE like below to do the comparison in character set.

```
SELECT 'str1' = 'str2' COLLATE <charset>;
```

Comment: The problem occurs at insertion, I wasn't accurate. I edited the question to be more precise.